# How is this if statement evaluated

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var wait = function() {
   return setTimeout(function() {
      return 8;
   }, 1000);
}

var foo = function() {
   if (wait() === 8) {
      return 99;
   } else {
      return 23;
   }
}

console.log(foo());
```

prints 23

I understand function calls are asynchronous; however, how can the if block even be evaluated until the `wait()` function returns? How would the logic I'm trying to achieve  be successfully represented in javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I understand function calls are asynchronous;

Function calls are completely synchronous.

> how can the if block even be evaluated until the wait() function returns?

Your wait function immediately returns the result of setTimeout, which is the Timeout ID. the function you passed to setTimeout will be executed *sometime in the future*, and the return value will be lost.

> How would the logic I'm trying to achieve be successfully represented in javascript?

The Code you're likely looking for is this. I have manually converted your code into [Continuation Passing Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)

```
// `wait` takes a callback which is captured in it's closure to be used by
// the anonymous function passed to setTimeout, sometime in the future.
var wait = function(callback) {
   return setTimeout(function() {
      callback( 8 );
   }, 1000);
}

// `foo` also takes a callback that will be called when the function passed
// to `wait` is evaluated.
var foo = function(callback) {
   wait(function(value){
       if (value === 8) {
          callback( 99 );
       } else {
          callback( 23 );
       }
    }
}

// Finally, `foo` is called with another callback, this time logging the value.
foo(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
})
```

Answer (score 4):

> *"I understand function calls are asynchronous"*

No, function calls are synchronous.

When you call `foo()`, it (obviously) executes this line:

```
if (wait() === 8) {
```

...which calls `wait()`. The `wait()` function *immediately* returns the value returned by `setTimeout()`, which is a timeout id that can be used with `clearTimeout()`. This timeout id is not likely to be `8`, so then the `else` case is done.

`setTimeout()` doesn't care about the return value of the function you pass to it, so the `return 8` "disappears" - nothing is done with that value.

The function that you pass to `setTimeout()` is queued up to be executed later: this will occur after the specified delay (1000ms) or after the current function (and whatever called it) finishes executing, whichever comes later.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [Timeout explains](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

from here, and try [timeout test](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_settimeout2) you will know that `wait` is only the id of the timeout object. You can even clear the timeout object by calling `clearTimeout(wait)` when you are still  in 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the setTimeout function will return an integer which is used with the clearTimeout method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536753(v=vs.85).aspx

The wait() method returned 1, so if block is not executed. But after 1000 ms the setTimeout function is executed.